# How to cut off div gradually

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How do I cut off "A Outer" or others such as div/img/some elements as the browser screen goes under "A"?

A pic is better than thousand words, so here's a pic...[image]

A and A outer are the same class. it just A outer is the area that expand by the children.

Comment: Why are all the elements in the image named "A"; instead of "outer", "inner" and "qwe"? Which is which?

Comment: updated question...should be better now?

Comment: I think I know what you mean. You want "A outer" to scale down till 0px before "A" scales down. This is only possible using javascript and setting new "width: x%;" on resize event.

Comment: @HoschNok exactly....I am not a person who good at express with words... indeed it will be some nasty javascript, thats why i will it find out css way first before turn into javascript :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as you said, the width of divs are fixed values, then you can use @media queries for this very easily.

```
@media (max-width=...px){
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Andrew not sure if this is what you are trying to accomplish, but take a look at this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/moojjoo/ppz8et2r/2/

I made the width to be 300px instead of 100px.  Simply resize the Window to see the effects.  Your outer columns will be hidden.

HTML

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

#left {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
}

#middle {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
}

#right {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
  
  #left {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  
  #middle {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
  }
  
  #right {
    visibility: hidden
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="left">This is my left outer div</div>
  <div id="middle">This is my middle div</div>
  <div id="right">This is my right outer div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Andrew I support a site that gets 283,847 users a month.  From that only 3772 visits are from IE 8.0 and below.   It is time to move forward.  The other solution would be to write some nifty jQuery or JavaScript for your solution.

Comment: I understand, I hate IE 7 and 8 so much to the point that I curse to the people who using it...but I need to keep my job :(

Comment: @Andrew you might be able to make a strong case and keep your job :-)

Comment: Ok, my next question is why would someone with IE 8 and below be under 100px width?  Most of them would not be adjusting their browser on there desktop or notebook under 100px.  When I hear 100px I think mobile.  Does that make sense?

Comment: If you like my answer please up vote or accept as answer.  I am close to a 200 reputation.  :) *CHEERS*